# toggle inside reducer In react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

In my reducer file, created actions which is

```
[actions.toggle]: state => ({
      ...state,
      move: false,
    }),
```

In jsx file , my constructor is

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    store.dispatch(actions.toggle());
    this.state ={
    enableMove: store.getState.move
    }
 }
```

I also created a function to work with toggle

```
 toggleShowMove(){
 this.setState({
    enableMove: !this.state.enableMove,
 })
 }
```

Inside my render

```
 <button onClick={() => this.toggleShowMove()}></button>

<div>{this.state.enableMove && <div>Hello</div>}</div>
```

The toggle works perfectly. But I want to change toggle value inside reducer. How can I toggle property inside reducer?

Comment: you have to dispatch actions.toggle() inside toggleShowMore method and use move state from store inside render method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use the value from state inside reducer and toggle it instead of setting `move` to false

```
[actions.toggle]: state => ({
  ...state,
  move: !Boolean(state.move),
}),
```